# How to make a front page of a game in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to program a game for an assignment. I have the guts of it done, but I need something at the beginning to say the rules etc.

In order to do this, I have used the 'if' statement so it checks when the space bar is pressed and thus starts the game. However, when another key is pressed it just goes back to the starting page.

Is there a way to stop this?

This is my code:

```
int direction = 1;
float points = 0;
float speed = 1;
float distance;

PImage bg;
//https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/Preview-Cave-Parallax.png

goal[] goals = new goal[10];
goal[] level2 = new goal[15];



player p;
void setup() {
    bg = loadImage("bg.png");
    size(800,800);
    background(bg);
    smooth();
    noStroke();

    goals[0] = new goal(40, 100, 60, 1, -1);
    goals[1] = new goal(60, 200, 40, 2, 1);
    goals[2] = new goal(50, 200, 30, 4, -1);
    goals[3] = new goal(16, 250, 30, 3, 1);
    goals[4] = new goal(30, 300, 50, 1.5, -1);
    goals[5] = new goal(40, 350, 60, 5, -1);
    goals[6] = new goal(60, 400, 40, 2, 1);
    goals[7] = new goal(50, 450, 30, 2.5, -1);
    goals[8] = new goal(16, 500, 30, 3, 1);
    goals[9] = new goal(30, 550, 50, 2, -1);

    level2[0] = new goal(40, 100, 60, 1, -1);

    p = new player();
}

void draw() {

    //The starting page

    background(bg);
    fill(0);
    rect(0, 325, 800, 340);
    fill(255);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    textSize(50);
    text("Welcome", 400, 350);
    textSize(30);
    text("Rules: Don't let the red balls touch you!", 400, 450);
    text("Controls: Use arrows to move to the left or right.", 400, 500);
    text("Press Space to start.", 400, 550);



    //The Game

    if(key == ' '){
         background(bg);
        fill(255);
        textSize(30);
        text("Score:", 50, 50);
        text(points, 140, 50);
        p.show();
        p.move();
        for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
            if (i%2 == 0){
                goals[i].show();
                goals[i].move();
            }
        }

        if(points >= 2){
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
                if(i%3 == 0){
                    goals[i].show();
                    goals[i].move();
                }
            }
        }

        if(points >= 3) {
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
                goals[i].show();
                goals[i].move();
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            distance = dist((p.x), (p.y), (goals[i].x), (goals[i].y));
            if(distance <=(15+goals[i].w/2)){

                background(0);
                fill(255);
                textSize(50);
                textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
                text("GAME OVER", 400, 400);
                noLoop();
            }
        }

        if(p.y == 15 || p.y == 785){
            points = points + 0.5;
            fill(255);
            textSize(30);
            text(points, 140, 50);

        }
    }
    //else {

    // }
}

class goal {
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float c;
    float speed;
    float direction;
    goal(float xpos, float ypos, float wd, float sp,  float dr) {
        x = xpos;
        y = ypos;
        w = wd;
        speed = sp;
        direction = dr;  
    }

    void show() {
        fill(255,0,0);
        ellipse(x,y,w,w);
    }
    void move() {
        x = x + (speed * direction);
        if ((x > 800-w/2) || (x <w/2)) {
            direction = direction * -1;
        } 
    }
}

class player {
    float x = 400;
    float y = 750;
    float speed = 1;
    int direction = 1;
    void show() {
        fill(255);
        ellipse(x, y, 30, 30);
    }
    void move() {
        y = y +(speed * direction);
        if ((y>785)||(y<15)){
            direction = direction*-1;
        }


        if (key == CODED){

            if (keyCode == LEFT){
                if (x >15){
                    x--;
                }
            }
            else if (keyCode == RIGHT){
                if (x <785){
                    x++;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to this so I'm not really sure as to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way for you to do this is to have a variable that holds the current state of the game. For example: `String state = "title";`.

Then, when the player presses space, you change the state from `"title"` to `"game"` (or whatever you want to name them). You'll want to check this at the beginning of your draw function.

When you are drawing, you check the state to determine whether to draw the title screen or the game. Eg: `if(state.equals("title")) { drawTitle(); }`. Etc.

I would also suggest having your logic in a main `gameLoop()`, while the actual drawing to the screen is in separate methods which are called as appropriate from the game loop, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Please do not use `==` to compare `String` values. Use the `equals()` function instead.

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing much more JavaScript than Java lately.